# What is the probability $P(A | A \cup B)$ generally for mutually exclusive events $A$ and $B$?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have mutually exclusive events $A$ and $B$. What would

$$
P(A\mid A \cup B)
$$

evaluate to?

would it be

$$
P(A\mid A \cup B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}
$$

generally?

Comment: What is **or**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it be
>
> $$ \begin{align}P(A\mid A \cup B) &= \frac{P(A)}{P(A \cup B)}\tag 1\\[1ex]& = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}\tag 2\end{align}$$
>
> generally?

Yes.  Well, generally for any $A$ and $B$ that are disjoint (aka mutually exclusive).

The first is by definition of conditional probability, plus that $A=A\cap(A\cup B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

The second is by the law of additivity of probabilities of disjoint events.